# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_FOREACH, expecting ')'

Tags: php

```
foreach ($hotel['dop'] as $dopvalueid => $dopvaluekey) {
    $countdop = 0;
    $HPROP[$dopvalueid] = array(
        foreach ($hotel['dop'][$dopvalueid] as $dopvalueotherkey => $dopvaluevalue)
        {
             $arDops["n".$countdop] = array(
                "VALUE" => $dopvaluevalue,
                "DESCRIPTION" => ""
            );
        $countdop++;
        }
    );
}
```

Выдает ошибку Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_FOREACH, expecting ')'on line 4

Что может быть не так?

Comment: круто, с утра подняло настроение :)

Comment: Форыч в аррае не фурычит. =)

Comment: огада :)))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

foreach из массива $HPROP[$dopvalueid] уберите, должно помочь :)

Comment: а как мне тогда формировать $HPROP[$dopvalueid] = array(?

Comment: Ну как, сначала также выше сформируйте $arDops после чего передайте его уже в $HPROP[$dopvalueid]